# Django Social Auth (Google OAuth 2) - AuthCancelled even when "Allow access" is clicked

Tags: django, authentication, django-socialauth

I am successfully using Django Social Auth to login users with Facebook. I'm trying to implement Google OAuth2. I have taken all the steps I know of to integrate it, but I'm getting an `AuthCanceled at /complete/google-oauth2/` exception even when I click `Allow access`. Here's what I did to integrate it:

- Went to the Google API console, registered my application and got my Client ID and Client Secret.
- I added the correct return url `http://mysite/complete/google-oauth2`, before I did that I got "unauthorized redirect url" from Google.
- In my settings.py I have

  ```
  GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '*****'
  GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '*****'

  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
      'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
      'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
      'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
  )
  ```
- I guess I have the other relevant settings right, as Facebook login works, and I'm able to show the window, view my app name in the Google authorization window, etc.

Whan am I doing wrong? How can I fix/debug that AuthCancelled exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by a strange Google behavior: when I initially created my client ID, google gave me this client ID: `193271111225.apps.googleusercontent.com`. After a conversation with the library author, he told me that his ids were much longer, so I created a new client ID with the exact same settings. The new ID generated was `193271111225-cvltnldi4hh5lmo784v2ir451b3rij7e.apps.googleusercontent.com` and with it, it worked. Both IDs look the same in the console, but only the latter works.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#exceptions-middleware) middleware for proper handling social_auth exception

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...,
    'social_auth.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error when I tried the `social-auth-app-django` library for social authentication.
And I was receiving the following error.

```
AuthCanceled at /social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```

Two silly mistakes lead to this error.

1. Not defining the redirect Authorized redirect URIs in the Client ID for the Web application.(set it to http://localhost:8000/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/)
2. The spelling mistake for SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET

So if you are receiving the same error, make sure you define the redirect authorize URIs and check your spelling.